# src="https://dns.firstblackphase.com/scripts/start.js"

Tags: plugins, server, code, scripts, virus

always this message appeared in my WordPress site

https://prnt.sc/MPFNisaNmFQq

https://prnt.sc/ADcQ8a5VbzKi

https://prnt.sc/qN65SdKELtmS

https://prnt.sc/DfB7XLarovbo

could you please help me to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your site has been compromised (or possibly your computer if its not just happening on your site?) - can you access the admin area? If so I would recommend getting a plugin such as Wordfence which can help you to locate and remove any affected code and files?